# Stop ZSH from reading .bashrc file

Tags: linux, terminal, linux-mint, zsh

I just recently switch to from Bash to Zsh. It seems that my .bashrc file is being read despite the fact that I am using Zsh. I see the result in the fact that following string '\u@\h [\033[32m]\w[\033[33m]$(parse_git_branch)[\033[00m]' is in my terminal prompt, which originates from my .bashrc file. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You've probably exported the `PS1` variable in your `.bashrc` which is fairly pointless. Just set it, don't use `export`. Merely setting a zsh prompt in `.zshrc` will resolve this as you've found by installing powerlevel9k.

Answer (score 0):

It seems installing the powerlevel9k theme solved this issue.

Comment: Note that powerlevel9k has been discontinued. Check its homepage.